# How can deep clone a list in c# while using a list of interfaces?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following interface

```
public interface IReportFilter
{
    IReportColumn ReportColumn { get; set; }

    FilterType Type { get; set; }

    string Value { get; set; }

    string FormattedValue { get; }

    string BuildSqlFilter(string parameterName);

    List<IReportFilter> SubFilters { get; set; }

    FilterOperator SqlOperator { get; set; }

    FilterOperator SubFiltersOperator { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class that implements it like this

```
public class ReportFilter : IReportFilter
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

From another class in my project I have the following code

```
List<IReportFilter> filters = new List<IReportFilter>
{
    new ReportFilter
    { 
        ReportColumn = new ReportColumn{ ColumnKey = "Result.IsCompleted"},
        Value = "1",
        SubFilters = new List<IReportFilter> 
        {
             new ReportFilter { SqlOperator = FilterOperator.Or, ReportColumn = new ReportColumn{ ColumnKey = "User.LastName"}, Value = "Jones"},
             new ReportFilter { SqlOperator = FilterOperator.Or, ReportColumn = new ReportColumn{ ColumnKey = "User.LastName"}, Value = "Smith"},
             new ReportFilter { SqlOperator = FilterOperator.Or, ReportColumn = new ReportColumn{ AggregateFunction = SqlAggregateFunctions.Count}, Type = FilterType.GreaterThenOrEqualTo ,Value = "0" },
        }
    },
};
```

I like to be able to pass my `filters` object to a method which will separate my filter based on a condition.

Here is a method that I write to separate my filters recursively

```
private List<IReportFilter> ExtractFiltersByAType(List<IReportFilter> filters, bool IsStandard = true)
{
    List<IReportFilter> validFilters = new List<IReportFilter>();

    foreach(var filter in filters)
    {

        if (filter.SubFilters != null && filter.SubFilters.Any())
        {
            //At this point we know there are some sub filters
            filter.SubFilters = ExtractFiltersByAType(filter.SubFilters, IsStandard);
        }

        if( (IsStandard && !IsAggregate(filter.ReportColumn.AggregateFunction) ) || (!IsStandard && IsAggregate(filter.ReportColumn.AggregateFunction) ) )
        {
            validFilters.Add(filter);
        }

    }

    return validFilters;
}
```

The problem with this method is that the variable `filters` gets passed by reference instead of creating a copy an object. 
Which means any change I make will change the original `filters` object! I really don't understand this behavior in C# and is making my life miserable!

Anyhow, I did some research and I found out that I need to deep clone my `filters` object before passing it to my method.

I tried to use the following method to deep clone my object

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
{
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
}
```

Then I used it like so

```
var copyOfFilters = Clone(filters);
```

but this is giving me an error because I my `SubFilters` object is constructed with an interface!

> Could not create an instance of type
>   ReportsEngine.Support.ReportsGenerator.Report.Contracts.IReportFilter.
>   Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
>   Path '[0].ReportColumn', line 1, position 17.

How can I correctly clone my object?

I am also curios to know which why such behavior exists in c#?

Comment: If something like `filters` were passed by value, then every time you passed them into a method the system would have to copy all of the filters, subfilters, etc., out to a separate area of memory, even if you weren't planning to modify them at all. That would make programs perform very badly.

Comment: I would like to agree with you on that. But when passing filters to my method the line `filter.SubFilters = ExtractFiltersByAType(filter.SubFilters, IsStandard);` impact the original one.

Comment: The most basic way to fix your Clone method would be to include type names during serialization. See docs on the [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm) setting.

Comment: mike z, how would I do that?

Comment: @Jaylen. It's there in the documentation, which has an example very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also curios to know which why such behavior exists in c#?

You cannot instantiate interfaces. Interfaces only give a contract that types needs to adhere to. It does not give an implementation for that contract though.

So when you attempt to deserialize some JSON into an interface type, this does not work since the deserializer cannot instantiate that (interface) type. It needs a concrete type instead—for example your `ReportFilter`. So you *could* call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportFilter>(serialized)` and it would work.

However, since you are doing this in a generic method, you attempt to deserialize it as type `T`. That type `T` comes from the generic type argument of the method which is inferred from the call to that method. In this case, you are likely passing a `IReportFilter` object, so *at compile time* that’s the type that’s being used for `T` (regardless of whether that object is an actual `ReportFilter`).

In order to change that, you would have to call it explicitly as a `ReportFilter`:

```
var copyOfFilter = Clone((ReportFilter)filter);
```

Comment: That did not work for me I get curtly red lines under it. because filters is `List<IReportFilter>` not `IReportFilter`  I tried to change it to `var copyOfFilter = Clone( (List<ReportFilter>) filters);` but also giving me an error

Comment: @Jaylen Try `Clone(filters.Cast<ReportFilter>().ToList())`

Comment: I get this error `{"Could not create an instance of type ReportsEngine.Support.ReportsGenerator.Report.Contracts.IReportColumn. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].ReportColumn.Title', line 1, position 26."}`